# Opening Local Pages in InternetExplorer via VBScript

Tags: excel, internet-explorer, vbscript, automation

I'm trying to automate some functions here and in order to do that, I've build a simple system:

In a local web-page you input all the data you need and, once you press a button, all this data is transferred to a Excel sheet.

Good news is: It works. Bad news? Not in every computer.

You see, everything is started when the user opens a VBScript. This script opens the page and listens to some actions. When such actions are performed, it then closes the page and write it's contents into the excel file.

When I execute this script in my home computer, it works like a charm, no problem whatsoever. When I try to execute this in the office, however, the story is quite different.

It seems IE loses a part of it's identity when opening my local page because once I've altered the page to Google, it worked.

```
FilePath = "C:\Hours"
PageFilePath = FilePath & "\HourAppointment.html"
'PageFilePath = "www.google.com"

    Set objExplorer = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    objExplorer.Visible = 1

    objExplorer.Width   = 1200
    objExplorer.Height  = 700
    objExplorer.Left    = 10
    objExplorer.Top     = 10

    Call objExplorer.Navigate2( PageFilePath )
    Call WaitForIExplorer( objExplorer )

    objExplorer.Quit

Private Function WaitForIExplorer(objExplorer)

    Do until objExplorer.readyState = 4
        WScript.Sleep 1000
    Loop

    Do While objExplorer.Busy = True
        WScript.Sleep 1000
    Loop
End Function
```

The page opens itself as it should but as soon as the script engine tries to read it's readystate it fails.

I've tried a combination of things, such as setting a delay before reading the readystate (10 seconds+) but to no avail. It is also worth mentioning that the IE object is never null, I've checked it with the IsNull function and that I've fiddled with IE security settings, but didn't manage anything special, as I don't really know what changes to make.

So, does anyone knows what the heck is going on with my program?

Thanks to @Teemu, I was able to minimize the problem using only Busy and not readyState. Even so, I've added a new function:

```
    Private Function CheckValidity(objExplorer)
      CheckValidity = False

      Set bodyContent = objExplorer.Document.Body.All

      saveValue     = bodyContent.savePressed.Value
      appointValue  = bodyContent.newAppointmentPressed.Value

      If ((saveValue = "SAVE") _
        And (appointValue = "SAVE")) Then

        CheckValidity = True
      End If
    End Function
```

When trying to get the Document Body, it fails with Interface Unknown Error. I understand this is because the page is not fully loaded but I am not sure, as I've placed another Sleep call before that with no change.

EDIT: Using my answer below, I've noticed that the problem also occurs because IE is blocking scripts on the page and asks me to enable them. When I click to do so, it reloads the page and this causes the Script to get lost. I have no fix for this as of now, I'm looking into it.

Comment: I think I should note that I'm using a lot of JQuery in the web page, such as JQuery, JQuery UI and JQuery DataTables.

Comment: `objExplorer.`[`Busy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms970456.aspx) should do the trick. `objExplorer` (it's an ActiveX object, not a browser `document`) has no property `readyState`.

Comment: Thanks @Teemu , but then how does the non-local pages work or even the local page in my home computer? I've tried your fix and was presented with a Unspecified Error. I've switched the Busy and readystate so Busy would come first.

Comment: If you'll peek behind the link I posted, you can also find `browser.Document`...

Comment: Oh, sorry, didn't catch that before... So I've placed the Busy call before the readyState one and altered it to 
        `Do until objExplorer.Document.readyState = 4`
 But the error is still rampant on the readyState

Comment: @Teemu: I've updated the question with new problems, but your comment did help me, thanks! The funny thing is: why does my home PC works with the same code?

Comment: Actually, you should use `ReadyState = 4` rather than `Busy`, because they basically do the same thing, but the former is more reliable than the latter. And you have yet to provide any information at all about how exactly your code fails. So I'd suggest you refrain from adding more code (which would warrant a new question anyway) before you solved the problem you have with the existing code.

Comment: Thanks @AnsgarWiechers. I cannot provide more details on the failure because I don't have them, I just get a VB popup saying Interface Unknown on this line: `Set bodyContent = objExplorer.Document.Body.All`. Since I'm home now, I can assure you that it does work, I've just ran it successfully. However, it does not run well in my office PC. I'm suspecting IE configurations, but I do not have enough knowledge to be sure of it.

Comment: I don't doubt that it works in general. However, you probably don't need help with those cases where it works, but rather with those where it doesn't. Troubleshooting this becomes quite hard when you can't reproduce the issue. Even more so when we're not the ones sitting in front of your computer (meaning we don't see what you see).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a "fix" for this problem. As I suspected, the problem lies in the speed which VB code is run and the speed which IE can open the page.

What I've done is simply put a `MsgBox()` that should only be closed once the whole page is loaded. It works like a charm but leaves this feeling of "this is not the way it's supposed to be".

I'm classifying this as a answer since it does solve my problem, but I would love to have a better solution.

Thank you all for your help.